# Issue with hosting website on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage, vs-web-site-project

Hosted website on google cloud, the PHP pages dont open in browser instead the webpage download, html pages work fine

we had a website hosted on hostinger it worked fine there, i have pointed my cname to google setup a bucket and all & uploaded files on public html from hostinger to this bucket

How to i get my php website to work on google cloud

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy LAMP stack on your GCP instance. Here are the steps to setup LAMP stack:

Install Apache and PHP on your instance

**Debian 8 and Ubuntu 14**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

**Debian 9 and Ubuntu 16/17**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php
```

**CentOS 6 and 7**

Install Apache and PHP:

```
sudo yum check-update
sudo yum -y install httpd php
```

Start the Apache service:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Optional: Set the Apache service to start automatically:

```
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

For complete documentation: [Setting up LAMP on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp)

Comment: Hi i deployed LAMP using https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/lamp, how do i go about uploading the files ? will i be looking for a public html ? where do i find the directory